# How to get a value provider to read updated values in angular

Tags: angular, components, provider, angular-providers, mat-datepicker

I have an application that people log into. In their profile they can choose their own input and output date formats. To accommodate this I made a customDatePicker component. In the value provider inside the @componet decorator I use a MY_FORMATS variable that tells the matdatePicker how to format the dates. The parse dateInput and the display dateInput come from an environment variable inside my app.

The problem is that the @component is hit when the application initializes and uses the default dates in my environment variable. After the user logs in is when the date formats in the environment variable are updated with the user data. But the @component never looks at the updated data.

What can I do to fix this? Also, there is the possibility that the user could change their chosen date formats while logged in and I need the component to register that change as well. But I can't seem to get the value provider in the @component decorator to ever look at the date formats variable again.

Thank you for all your help. If you decide to answer this can you please give a detailed explanation. I'm new to coding and something vague will probably not help me.

```js
export let MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: env.inDateFormat.toUpperCase(),
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: env.outDateFormat.toUpperCase(),
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'DD MMM YYYY',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-datepicker',
  templateUrl: './custom-datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-datepicker.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomDatepickerComponent),
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a stackblitz that I was able to edit and use to solve my problem. It required putting the format in an injectable service instead of leaving it in the value provider. I'm still hoping someone can give me a way to use the above method instead. But here is the link to the stackblitz that was able to help me work around the issue. https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-picker-format-change?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts